# TypeError: Function.prototype.name sham getter called on non-function ONLY when I run with `--coverage`

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Whe I run my tests with `--coverage`

```
 yarn run test --coverage
```

The follow erro appear

```
component › should render with message if error occour

TypeError: Function.prototype.name sham getter called on non-function

  14 |              );
  15 |
> 16 |              expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
     |                              ^
  17 |      });
  18 |
  19 |      it("should render if error occour", function() {

  at Function.getName (../node_modules/function.prototype.name/implementation.js:31:9)
  at displayNameOfNode (../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:156:95)
  at ReactSixteenAdapter.displayNameOfNode (../node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:605:62)
  at typeName (../node_modules/enzyme/build/Debug.js:60:43)
  at internalNodeToJson (../node_modules/enzyme-to-json/mount.js:70:31)
  at mountToJson (../node_modules/enzyme-to-json/mount.js:93:12)
  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (../node_modules/enzyme-to-json/index.js:14:32)
  at Object.print (../node_modules/enzyme-to-json/createSerializer.js:22:40)
  at printPlugin (../node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.js:287:16)
  at prettyFormat (../node_modules/pretty-format/build/index.js:485:16)
  at Object.throwingMatcher (../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:320:33)
  at Object.toMatchSnapshot (src/components/molecules/ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary.test.jsx:16:19)
```

That is my `ErrorBoundary` component

```
import React from "react";

export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hasError: false };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, hasError: true }));
    }

    render() {
        const { hasError } = this.state;
        const { children, message = "Ops, ocorreu um erro. Tente novamente" } = this.props;

        return hasError ? <h1>{message}</h1> : children;
    }
}
```

And my test..

```
import React from "react";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";

describe("<ErrorBoundary> component", function() {
    it("should render with message if error occour", function() {
        function ProblemChild() {
            throw new Error("Error thrown from problem child");
        }

        const wrapper = mount(
            <ErrorBoundary message="Ops, algum erro ocorreu">
                <ProblemChild />
            </ErrorBoundary>
        );

        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, have you made any progress with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just solved this in my code base. The problem was caused by the missing class name on the export, so your fix is likely to be adding the class name in your `ErrorBoundary` component and anywhere else it's missing. i.e.

Change: `export default class extends React.Component {`

To: `export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {`

Hope it helps!

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, unless `enzyme-to-json` is passing a misbehaving Proxy into enzyme's utilities.

Comment: Can confirm also fixed this issue for me, thank you! We were extending a component that extended a third party component, and didn't see this issue until the a newer version of the upstream component changed how they were exporting their class. Fortunately, setting a class name on our export was enough to resolve the issue and we didn't have to request changes upstream.

Comment: This solution helped me as well